# running tsc in expo project with husky via lint-staged keeps generating js files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, expo

I have an expo project that uses typescript, originally generated via

```
expo init myApp --template @native-base/expo-template-typescript
```

I added husky and have a lint staged definition that simply says this:

```
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,jsx}": [
      "eslint --cache --fix"
    ],
    "*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
      "eslint --cache --fix"
    ]
  },
```

When tsc runs via the pre-commit hook this way it incorrectly checks the node_modules files, and also generates .js files of all the .tsx files that were checked in my `src` dir. However, running the following simple package.json command via `yarn lint` does ***not*** do those incorrect actions

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*{js,ts,jsx,tsx}' --fix && tsc",
    ...
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fix

Add `--noEmit` to prevent JavaScript from being generated.

## More

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*{js,ts,jsx,tsx}' --fix && tsc --noEmit",
    ...
  },
```

Perhaps this is already setup by the `tsconfig.json` so `--project tsconfig.json` might also work:

```
   "scripts": {
    ...
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*{js,ts,jsx,tsx}' --fix && tsc --project tsconfig.json",
    ...
   },
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened when I added husky and lint-staged to my expo project. When I run `yarn tsc` from the command line, it works perfectly. The problem was with lint-staged. [I tried this solution](https://github.com/lint-staged/lint-staged/issues/825#issuecomment-620018284) and got it to work. What you need to do is create a `lint-staged.config.js` file and put your lint-staged commands in the file like below.

```
module.exports = {
    "*.{js,jsx}": [
    "eslint --cache --fix"
  ],
  "*.{ts,tsx}": [
    () => "tsc --project tsconfig.json",
    "eslint --cache --fix"
  ]
};
```

The key solution here is **() => "tsc --project tsconfig.json"**